# Android - How changing cursor in a CursorAdapter affects UI?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

Before I start a full blown DB table project that is shown in a list, I'd like to understand better on what happens to the UI when the DB data is changed.

Imagine showing a list of 1000 items using a cursor adapter. Now some rows are added/deleted to/from the list. Now a new cursor needs to be loaded into the the Cursor adapter (using [changeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor))).

**What happens to the list (ListView) shown to the user? Does the user sees this reload? Does the list stays in the same place?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a quick test, looks like the adapter uses positions to navigate.

After the cursor is swapped the adapter stays at the previous position.

If the new cursor has less available items (thus less positions), the last visible item will be the last item in the cursor.

Basically the list won't move visually as long as items up until the last visible item don't change.

---

As for the technical stuff:

First of all `changeCursor` acts the same as `swapCursor` the only difference being that `changeCursor` also closes the previous cursor.

Once `swapCursor` is called and the new cursor is not null, `notifyDataSetChanged` gets called.

If you had enough `convertViews` (re-usable views) created before the swap, `bindView` is called on the visible views, to change the text / images or w/e you bind to your views. That change is obviously visible to the user.

If however you didn't have enough views then `newView` is called and views are created before calling `bindView` as above. Again this will be visible to the user because new items are added to the list.

Comment: As someone who uses in memory lists with the ListAdapter, I understand from your answer, that there's not much difference between changing a cursor and changing the list. Thanks.